# GNU screen and less: overwriting previous output

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I'm in the process of switching from multiple tabs in iTerm to one GNU `screen` session. In iTerm, I can look at a file with `less` and the content of the terminal is restored when I quit `less`. In GNU `screen`, the previous contents get overwritten by the content of the file I looked at in `less`. Is there some way to change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding

```
altscreen on
```

to your .screenrc.